# Laravel Controller: AJAX post request data placed in request content

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm sending a POST request to my **ItemController**, the request came through and the response can be generated. But I am unable to extract the data passed by the AJAX request.

Here's a snippet script/blade template content: **layout.blade.php**:

```
<script>
$("#ajaxRequest").click(
    function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/itemAjaxReq',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            contentType:'application/json',
            headers:{'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
            data: 
            { 
                data1: 'ABC', 
                data2: 'DEF'                       
            },
            error: function() {alert('Error');},
            success: function(response) {                                                    
                        $('#ajaxResponse').empty();
                        $('#ajaxResponse').append(response);
                    }
    });
</script>

<div>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <button id="ajaxRequest">Test ajax request</button>
</div>

<div id="ajaxResponse">
</div>
```

Route: **web.php**

```
Route::post('itemAjaxReq','ItemController@ajaxReq')->name('items.ajaxReq');
```

Model: **ItemController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Item;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class ItemController extends Controller
{   
    //... some skipped functions
    public function ajaxReq()
    {
        if(request()->ajax())
        {
            \error_log("This is an AJAX Request");
            //dd(request());
            $data = request()->all();
            //dd($data);
            \error_log("Request :\n" . request() . "\n");
            \error_log("data1 : " . request()->input('data1'));
            \error_log("data2 : " . request()->data2);
            \error_log("data3 : " . request()->data3);
            return "Response :\n"."Some data here";
        }
    }
}
```

If I uncomment the `dd($data)`, I got empty array (`[]`). If I uncomment the `dd(request())`, then the data appear on the protected variable `#content`. Here's the snippet:

```
Illuminate\Http\Request {#51 ▼
  #json: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#43 ▶}
  #convertedFiles: null
  #userResolver: Closure($guard = null) {#31 ▶}
  #routeResolver: Closure() {#253 ▶}
  +attributes: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#53 ▶}
  +request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#43 ▶}
  +query: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#59 ▶}
  +server: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ServerBag {#55 ▶}
  +files: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag {#56 ▶}
  +cookies: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#54 ▶}
  +headers: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag {#57 ▶}
  #content: "data1=ABC&data2=DEF"
  #languages: null
  #charsets: null
  #encodings: null
  #acceptableContentTypes: null
  #pathInfo: "/itemAjaxReq"
  #requestUri: "/itemAjaxReq"
  #baseUrl: ""
  #basePath: null
  #method: "POST"
  #format: null
  #session: Illuminate\Session\Store {#273 ▶}
  #locale: null
  #defaultLocale: "en"
  -preferredFormat: null
  -isHostValid: true
  -isForwardedValid: true
  basePath: ""
  format: "html"
}
```

If I expanded `+attributes`, `+request`, and `+query` properties, I got `#parameters: []`

Did I make mistake when passing the data? How do I extract it from the content attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've solved the issue. But I don't understand why the solution works.

I changed the AJAX request `contentType` from `contentType:'application/json'` to `contentType:'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`

The problem isn't on using not using `$request`, nor fetching it via `->post('data1')` or `->input('data1')`. Using `request()` or directly fetching it by `->data1` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel >= 5.5, you can simply call

```
$request->post() or $request->post('my_param')
```

which internally calls

```
$request->request->all() or $request->request->get('my_param')
```

respectively.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Trying to print out `request()->post()` gave `500 Internal server error`

Comment: Check the server log.

Comment: It says: 

`local.ERROR: Array to string conversion {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Array to string conversion at D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laravelmongodb\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\ItemController.php:129)`

Line 129 is where I printed the request:
`\error_log("Request :\n" . request()->post() . "\n");`